# Nested sorting of levels by the sum of another column

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a better way of performing sorting of levels within groups by the sum of another column.

Within each key (e.g. `K1` in the sample data), the levels (e.g. `x, y` in the sample data) should be sorted in descending order by the sum of a numeric column (`size` in the sample data). More generally, I might have N keys (i.e. from K_1 to K_N).

I cant think of any other way than to perform the aggregate first then lookup the rank for each key then sort the whole table using the concatenated key.

Is there a better way of doing this using some combination of base + data.table syntax i.e. faster or shorter way of solving this problem?

**Sample data**:

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(K1=c("x","x","y","y","y"), 
    K2=c("K","R","R","G","G"), 
    K3=1:5,
    size=c(1, 2.5, 4, 3.5, 1),
    key=c("K1","K2","K3"))

#   K1 K2 K3 size
#1:  x  K  1  1.0
#2:  x  R  2  2.5
#3:  y  G  4  3.5
#4:  y  G  5  1.0
#5:  y  R  3  4.0
```

**Desired output**:

```
   K1 K2 K3 size
    y  G  4  3.5
    y  G  5  1.0
    y  R  3  4.0
    x  R  2  2.5
    x  K  1  1.0
```

**Example walkthrough using the sample data**:

For K1, the sum of `size` for y is 8.5 which is greater than the sum of `size` for x, which is 3.5 hence y should be above x in the rank.

Within K1=y,the sum of `size` for G is 4.5 which is greater than the sum of `size` for R, which is 4.0, hence G should be above R in the rank within K1=y.

Within K1=y & K2=G, the `size` for K3=4 is 3.5 which is greater than the `size` for K3=5 of 1.0, hence K3=4 should come above K3=5.

**What I have tried so far (which seems convoluted)**:

```
dat[, rank:=""]
for (n in seq_along(key(dat))) {
    x <- key(dat)[seq_len(n)]

    #name of dummy column
    col <- last(paste0(x, "_rank"))

    #aggregate by desired key
    rankDT <- dat[, list(size=sum(as.numeric(size), na.rm=TRUE)), by=x]

    #rank the size column in descending order then left pad this rank to equal number of digits
    rankDT[,(col) := formatC(
        frank(-size, ties.method="first"), 
        width=ceiling(.N/10), 
        format="d", 
        flag="0")]

    #concatenate this rank to the existing list of rank
    dat[rankDT,
        rank := paste0(rank, get(col)),
        on=x]
}
dat[order(rank)]
```

**Test Case 2**

```
dat <- data.table(K1=c("x","x","y","y","y"), 
    K2=c("K","R","R","G","G"), 
    K3=1:5,
    size=c(1, 16, 4, 3.5, 10),
    key=c("K1","K2","K3"))

#   K1 K2 K3 size
#1:  x  K  1  1.0
#2:  x  R  2 16.0
#3:  y  G  4  3.5
#4:  y  G  5 10.0
#5:  y  R  3  4.0
```

**Desired output for Test Case 2**:

```
   K1 K2 K3 size rank
    y  G  5 10.0  122
    y  G  4  3.5  124
    y  R  3  4.0  133
    x  R  2 16.0  211
    x  K  1  1.0  245
```

Tried searching for "recursive sort", "nested sort", "group + aggregate + rank". But these either sort alphabetically and/or sort by that particular column rather than sort based on another column.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Another shorter soln inspired by @Jaap

```
#factor to shift previous sum by so that when summing with latter sums, the previous ordering will not be corrupted
m <- dat[,max(abs(size))]

total <- Reduce(f=function(init, keys) {
        m * init + dat[, S:=sum(size), by=keys]$S
    }, 
    x=Reduce(c, key(dat), accumulate=TRUE), 
    init=dat[, rep(0, .N)])

dat[order(-total)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
cols <- setdiff(key(dat), 'K3')

dat[, Ksum := sum(size), by = cols][]
setorderv(dat, c('Ksum', cols), order = -1)
```

you get:

> ```
>    K1 K2 K3 size Ksum
> 1:  y  G  4  3.5  4.5
> 2:  y  G  5  1.0  4.5
> 3:  y  R  3  4.0  4.0
> 4:  x  R  2  2.5  2.5
> 5:  x  K  1  1.0  1.0
> ```

What this does:

- `cols <- key(dat)` creates a vector of column-names.
- `dat[, Ksum := sum(size), by = cols]` sums the values by the grouping columns and adds that as a new variable `Ksum` tot the *data.table*.
- `setorderv(dat, c('Ksum', cols), order = -1)` reorders the *data.table* by reference by a set of columns (including the sum-column: `c('Ksum', cols)`) in descending order (`order = -1`).

If you don't want to keep the `Ksum`-column, you can remove that with `dat[, Ksum := NULL]`:

> ```
> > dat[, Ksum := NULL][]
>    K1 K2 K3 size
> 1:  y  G  4  3.5
> 2:  y  G  5  1.0
> 3:  y  R  3  4.0
> 4:  x  R  2  2.5
> 5:  x  K  1  1.0
> ```

Comment: sorry its my bad. let me clarify the question to include more key levels from K1 ... Kn

Comment: thanks, Jaap. the correct order should be K3 == c(4,5,3,2,1) because size for K1==y and K2==G is 1.0 + 3.5 = 4.5 which should come above K1==y && K2==R whose size is 4.0

Comment: @chinsoon12 So you don't want to group by `K3`? Why do you use it as a key then? See also the update for a possibility.

Comment: Thanks, Jaap. I am still using K3 as it will help me decide if .(y, G, 4) or .(y, G, 5) comes first. Let me check if your soln works more generally. No R access now

Comment: thanks, Jaap! i added another test case and also a walkthrough on the sample data. i also tried your solution using `setorderv(dat, c('Ksum', 'size', cols), order = -1)` as well. it does not seem to work. i think it is missing a `Reduce`, `by`, `rbindlist`.